# How to perform less than/greater than comparisons on custom objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a custom class that has several members. I need to compare them to each other. javascript lets me write:

```
var a = new MyType(1);
var b = new MyType(2);
if (a < b) { ...
```

but I don't understand the behavior of the logical comparison. Can someone explain the semantics of the < comparison in the above code? Is there a way to control what happens so that I can get right behavior? I know I can write a comparison method for the class, but since javascript lets me write it, I wondered what it thought it was doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to define a `.valueOf` method that returns a primitive that can be used for comparison:

```
function MyType( value ){
    this.value = value;
}

MyType.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.value;
};

var a = new MyType(3),
    b = new MyType(5);

a < b
true
a > b
false
a >= b
false
b < a
false
b > a
true
```

If you don't define it, the the string `"[object Object]"` is used for comparison:

```
"[object Object]" < "[object Object]"
false
"[object Object]" > "[object Object]"
false
"[object Object]" >= "[object Object]"
true
"[object Object]" <= "[object Object]"
true
```

Comment: Wow that's like an IComparable interface for JavaScript.

Comment: @Jay when comparing objects for equality (`==`, `===`), it will always compare references (whether the 2 operands point to the same exact object in memory). You need to define method like `.isEqual` and call it normally `a.isEqual(b)`

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect. Bummer that it doesn't make either == or === work, though. Strange that I couldn't find this solution anywhere on the net.

Comment: @drdwilcox: It's existed in JavaScript for absolutely ages (since version 1.1 in 1996, I think) but seems oddly unknown.

Comment: I would have to agree with the unknown part. I've been writing javascript, even taught it to incoming web designers a couple of years, and never found this. And like I said, a google search came up completely empty. I'm sure googling `valueOf` would have found it, but that would have assumed I knew my answer.