# GroupBy using LinqJS

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I'd like to execute the `GroupBy` function using LinqJS but it seem's not working well...

My object :

[image: My object]

My code :

```
Enumerable.From(obj).GroupBy('{name: $.name}', null, '{name: $.name}').ToArray();
```

Result :

[image]

Should be :

```js
{name: toto, name: tata}
```

Comment: Do you need to get unique names in your array? Enumerable.From(obj).Select("x => x.name").Distinct().ToArray(); Maybe this?

Comment: The thing you need to realize is that if you ever project to an object for a key, you _must_ provide a comparer. It doesn't make sense to compare javascript objects (provided you don't define a [`valueOf()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10339506/390278) function), that's why you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the required function will look like:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.name, x => x.name, (baseName, names) => new {name = baseName}).ToArray();
```

So, in LinqJS, it will look like:

```
var result = Enumerable.From(obj).GroupBy('x => x.name', 'x => x.name', 'baseName, names => {name: baseName}').ToArray();
```

[image]

But, if you just need to get unique names, you can just use:

```
var result = Enumerable.From(obj).Select("x => x.name").Distinct().ToArray();
```

[image]