# Comparing two Objects by < and >

Tags: angular, typescript

Which method is used when checking if a object is bigger than another? I've tried to implement a compareTo Method but its only used when comparing if the Objects are equal (=).

For example

```
export class Check {
    check: string;
}
```

```
export class Test {
    constructor() {
        const c1 = new Check(),
        c1.check = '1-';
        const c2 = new Check(),
        c2.check = '1';
        console.log(c1 < c2); // returns false but in my case it should be true because 1- is not as good as 1
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10339568/1486848

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform less than/greater than comparisons on custom objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339506/how-to-perform-less-than-greater-than-comparisons-on-custom-objects-in-javascrip)

Comment: Thanks. It's the answer

Comment: Well that is a string comparison on you Test class property. What you can use, that works well for me is `localCompare` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/localeCompare