# Can you go without using function's ( ) while using conditional?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Sorry if my English bothers you but I've just come to realize you do not need to use ( ) with the function while using conditional - at least that's the case with ternary opeartor.

Here's my code:

```
let mark = {

fullName: 'Mark Wough',

mass: 100,

height: 1.8,

calcBMI: function()

return this.mass / (this.height * this.height;)

}

};



let john = {

fullName: 'John Smith',

mass: 90,

height: 1.5,

calcBMI: function()

return this.mass / (this.height * this.height;)

}

};

console.log(mark.calcBMI(, john.calcBMI());)

mark.calcBMI>john.calcBMI? console.log('Mark has higher BMI'): console.log('John has higher BMI');)
```

Notice I'm doing mark.calcBMI instead of mark.calcBMI() and both seem to be working!

Can any one please explain if that's exactly the way it is or I'm missing out on something and if its correct that you dont need to use ( ) in functions while using conditional, is this a good practice not to use them just because its optional or I should use them to be on the safer side?

Comment: `mark.calcBMI` and `mark.calcBMI()` are two very different things (regardless of conditional or not) - the first one is a reference to the function, the second one calls the function

Comment: @UnholySheep - Thank you but I believe you have to call a function first and then evaluate if a condition is true! For example, if I haven't called the function then how the heck will I compare it to something? (Sorry, I'm new to JS)

Comment: Change your code to make mark have a higher BMI - you'll see that it's not working as intended.

Comment: JavaScript performs certain implicit conversions under the hood, see the last part of this answer for a bit more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10339568/2878796

Comment: @NickParsons - Oh yes, you're correct, with my original code its not logging to the console Mark has higher BMI even when it is but if i add ( ) to the function, it does. IDK, why it doesnt give me the error for not adding ( ) after function name

Answer (score 0):

In your code `mark.calcBMI` and `john.calcBMI` are both references to functions. So when you perform:

```
mark.calcBMI > john.calcBMI
```

you're checking if one function is larger than another (note that these are function values, not the returned value from calling these functions). So the above is more or less analogous to writing:

```
(function() {}) > (function() {})
```

As it doesn't make sense to ask if one function value is larger than another, JavaScript will try to convert both functions to [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) (primitives being types such as strings, numbers, booleans, etc). As functions are objects, JavaScript will call the `.toString()` method both of the functions, which will convert the function objects to primitive strings. JavaScript does this conversion for us, so behind the scenes it gets interpreted as:

```
"function() {}" > "function() {}"
```

Now that both functions are strings, they can be compared. Since the left-hand side string is not larger than the right-hand side string (they're equal), you get `false` as a result. The same idea applies for your `calcBMI` functions for both john and mark. As their `.toString()` values are both the same you'll get false when comparing the two functions.

This means that you need to use parenthesis `( )` when calling your functions<sup>1</sup>, otherwise:

```
mark.calcBMI > john.calcBMI
```

... will always evaluate to `false` given that both `calcBMI` toString methods return the same string.

See example below for further understanding:

```js
const ex1 = (function() {}) > (function() {});
console.log("ex1", ex1);

const ex2 = (function(a) {}) > (function(b) {});
console.log("ex2", ex2);

const ex3 = (function(b) {}) > (function(a) {});
// "function(b) {}" > "function(a) {}", code unit of "b" larger is than the code unit of "a" so the result is `true` 
console.log("ex3", ex3);
```

<sup>1. the exception to this is if your methods are [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)</sup>